# Why does this node.js code fails if there is no blank return at the end of catch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been learning Node and although I understand all the code, and what is does, one thing is bothering me. So this is the code:

```
const http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

// array of mime types
var mimeTypes = {
  "html" : "text/html",
  "jpeg" : "image/jpeg",
  "jpg" : "image/jpeg",
  "png" : "image/png",
  "js" : "text/javascript",
  "css" : "text/css"
}

// create Server
http.createServer( (req, res) => {
  var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var fileName = path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(uri));
  console.log('Loading ' + process.cwd() + uri);
  var stats;

try{

  stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName);

} catch(err) {

  res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
  res.write('404 Not found\n');
  res.end();
  return; // if I remove this my code fails.
}

// check if file or directory

if (stats.isFile()) {
  var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(fileName).split(".").reverse()[0]]
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeType});

  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
  fileStream.pipe(res);
} else if (stats.isDirectory()) {

  res.writeHead(200 , {
    "Location" : "index.html"
  });
  res.end();
} else {
  res.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
  res.write("500 Internal Error\n");
  res.end();


}

}).listen(8080);
```

So If I remove blank return inside catch block my code will fail.

With return:

[image: With return]

Without return:

[image: Without return]

Does return allows execution to continue, can anyone explain?
Thanks.

Comment: `return` stops the termination of the current block. So when you use `return` the below statements are not executed. Since reading `stats` throws an exception but caught inside a try catch block, program continue running and `stats` stays undefined. Then trying to access `stats.isFile()` throws an exception which is not caught.

Comment: This problem could be reduced to `function foo() { return; console.log("hello"); }  foo()`.

Comment: `lstatSync`, You do realise using any sync functions in node.js, is a sure way to cripple scale-ability.

Comment: @keith what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: Use `lstat` instead.

Comment: @keith thanks I did it with lstat, so you suggest avoiding lstatSync in favor of lstat?

Comment: Yes, `lstatSync` is basically going to hang your node.js process until it's finished getting stat information, blocking all other users until done.  Using callbacks is not pretty, so another suggestion is if you alter you code to use `async / await`, things would become much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will not `return` inside the `catch` block - the code will continue to run and will get to the following line:

```
stats.isFile()
```

Now, `stats` is not defined, since there was an exception there, so your code is actually `undefined.isFile()`, and this will throw another exception there.

Comment: So what you are saying I will not have the value of stats if I don't add return,  as the try catch will not return any value for stats variable.

Comment: No, this is not what I'm saying. Read it again :)

Comment: I get it now, my exception is not processed and is hitting another exception, but return ends that block and exist catch with proper value for stats.isFile() , is it smart idea to use blank return for these kind of cases?

Comment: Now this is correct. Regarding "smart idea" - if your code shouldn't continue to run - yes. It really depends on what is going in there...

Answer (score 3):

I think you expect that the `res.end()` will stop the function execution / request processing, but instead it only closes the response body. The response then can be returned but your code after try / catch block goes on and experiences problems. The only proper way to stop the execution is your `return;` statement.